# Python 3: Unexpected EOF when parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Using this code:

```
import random
import query
import sys

while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Choose a number between 0 and 10:'))
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number.")
        continue
    if number > 10:
        print('Your number is too large.')
        continue
    elif number < 0:
        print('Your number is too small.')
        continue
    break

result = random.randint(0, 10)

print("You're number: " + str(number))
print("Our number: " + str(result))

if number == result:
    print('Congratulations!')
else:
    print('Close, but no cigar.')

while True:
    try:
        answer = query.query_yes_no('Do you wish to contunue?')
        if answer == "yes":
            while True:
                try:
                    number = int(input('Choose a number between 0 and 10:'))
                except ValueError:
                    print("That is not a number.")
                    continue
                if number > 10:
                    print('Your number is too large.')
                    continue
                elif number < 0:
                    print('Your number is too small.')
                    continue
                break
            print("You're number: " + str(number))
            print("Our number: " + str(result))
            if number == result:
                print('Congratulations!')
                continue
            else:
                print('Close, but no cigar.')
                continue
        elif answer == "no":
            print('Goodbye.')
            break
        break
    break
exit()
```

I keep getting a `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. It says it is on line 60. I have tried removing the exit() and the breaks but that doesn't work. I'm sure it is something simple as I am still new to Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include another `except` for the first `try` inside your infinite `while` loop. That's why, it may be giving a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it! I took out the last 2 breaks and the exit() and added except:pass and it is working as intended now.